# Ошибка в запуске jar файла

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jar, package

Имеется **maven** проект с плагином компиляции **com.zenjava**

[image: Плагин]

В корне лежат 2 файла (proxy.txt, geckodriver.exe) и 1 папка(video). Они нужны для работы программы.

[image: Структура проекта]

После компиляции **jar** выскакивает ошибка:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at View.MainWindow.start(MainWindow.java:22)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:34)
```

Насколько я понимаю, **jar** не может найти мои файлы и как следствие, запустить FX приложение.

[image: Путь к jar]

Вопрос: что делать с этим и куда поместить файлы чтобы **jar** запустился
(P.S пробовал кидать в разные места - результат один)

Comment: Если компилить jfx: native(exe) то он запустится, если поместить мои файлы в native/{project}/app